# Create a Json using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, json, jq

I have a file which has list of cidr's. How can I create a big json with below format using bash script
**With single CIDR**

```
[{"source":"1.1.1.0/32","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":65535,"min":1},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}}]
```

**With Multiple CIDR**

```
[{"source":"1.1.1.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}},{"source":"2.2.2.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}},{"source":"3.3.3.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}}]
```

I wanted to do it with 200 entries. I have 0 knowledge how json works. Can someone please help me
I want to use that json as a variable in a bash script

The input CIDR file is like

```
1.1.1.0/22
2.2.2.0/24
5.5.5.0/21
6.6.0.0/16
```

I tried a given solution in a bash script but I am getting `\r` near every CIDR

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash

lel=$(while read cidr ; do 
   jq -n --arg CIDR "$cidr" '[{"source":$CIDR,"protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions": {"destinationPortRange":{"max": 65535,"min": 1},"sourcePortRange": {"min":521,"max": 65535}  }}]' 
done < lol)
echo $lel
```

lol file :

```
1.22.0.0/15
1.38.0.0/15
1.186.0.0/15
14.96.0.0/14
```

Output

```
[ { "source": "1.22.0.0/15\r", "protocol": "17", "isStateless": true, "udpOptions": { "destinationPortRange": { "max": 65535, "min": 1 }, "sourcePortRange": { "min": 521, "max": 65535 } } } ] [ { "source": "1.38.0.0/15\r", "protocol": "17", "isStateless": true, "udpOptions": { "destinationPortRange": { "max": 65535, "min": 1 }, "sourcePortRange": { "min": 521, "max": 65535 } } } ] [ { "source": "1.186.0.0/15\r", "protocol": "17", "isStateless": true, "udpOptions": { "destinationPortRange": { "max": 65535, "min": 1 }, "sourcePortRange": { "min": 521, "max": 65535 } } } ] [ { "source": "14.96.0.0/14\r", "protocol": "17", "isStateless": true, "udpOptions": { "destinationPortRange": { "max": 65535, "min": 1 }, "sourcePortRange": { "min": 521, "max": 65535 } } } ]
```

Comment: Before we can proceed, we of course need to see what the formatting of the file containing CIDRs looks like. Once we know how the inividual properties are listed (i.e. are the key-value pairs written on a single line for each CIDR , or is does the formatting use tab-delimited multi-line syntax etc. ) conversion to JSON should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Sure I will update the post

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues in your data and code:

1. You have an input file in DOS or Windows text file format.
2. Your code creates multiple single-element arrays rather than a single array with multiple elements.

Your input file, `lol`, appears to be a text file in DOS/Windows format.  This means that when a utility that expects a Unix text file as input reads the file, each line will have an additional carriage-return character (`\r`) at the end.

You should convert the file to Unix text file format.  This can be done with e.g. `dos2unix`.

As for your code, you can avoid the shell loop and let `jq` read the whole file in one go.  This allows you to create a single result array rather than a set of arrays, each with a single object, which your code does.

The following assumes that the only thing that varies between the elements of the top-level array in the result is the `source` value (there is nothing in the question that explains how the max and min values of the source and destination ports should be picked):

```bash
jq -n -R '
        [inputs] |
        map( {
                source: .,
                protocol: "17",
                isStateless: true,
                udpOptions: {
                        sourcePortRange: { min: 521, max: 65535 },
                        destinationPortRange: { min: 1, max: 65535 }
                }
        } )' cidr.txt
```

or in the same compact one-line form as in your question:

```bash
jq -n -R '[inputs]|map({source:.,protocol:"17",isStateless:true,udpOptions:{sourcePortRange:{min:521,max:65535},destinationPortRange:{min:1,max:65535}}})' cidr.txt
```

Using `inputs`, `jq` reads the remaining inputs. Together with `-R`, it will read each line of `cidr.txt` as a single string.  Putting this in an array with `[inputs]` we create an array of strings.  The `map()` call takes each string from this array and transforms it into the `source` value for a larger, otherwise static object.

Add `-c` to the invocation of `jq` to get "compact" output.

---

If you don't want to, or are unable to, convert the input data from DOS to Unix text form, you can remove the carriage-return characters from within the `jq` expression instead.

To do this, replace the `.` after `source:` with `(.|rtrimstr("\r"))`, including the outer parentheses.  This trims the carriage-return from the end of each string read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

This should get you the exact syntax you require:

In the example , the file containing your CIDR values is named `cidr.txt` and appears to contain only IP addresses along with subnets, i.e. other parameters remain constant. If you actually need to change these additional parameters (i.e. the port ranges you provided are not actually the same for all cidr then I will update my answer, and provide a fully fleshed out template)

Additionally, you will require 'jq' , which is the ubiquitous application for dealing with JSON through bash. It may likely already be installed these days, but if not then `sudo apt install jq` per usual.

```bash
while read cidr ; do 
   jq -n --arg CIDR "$cidr" '{"source":$CIDR,"protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions": {"destinationPortRange":{"max": 65535,"min": 1},"sourcePortRange": {"min":521,"max": 65535}  }}'  
done < cidr.txt | jq --slurp
```

Using the four-line file sample you provided, the output of the above will give you the following in the terminal:

```bash
[
  {
    "source": "1.1.1.0/22",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 65535,
        "min": 1
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "source": "2.2.2.0/24",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 65535,
        "min": 1
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "source": "5.5.5.0/21",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 65535,
        "min": 1
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "source": "6.6.0.0/16",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 65535,
        "min": 1
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

## UPDATE

In order to fix the above output, you need to "repair" the line termination of your CIDR file. There are two ways of doing so:

##### Answer 1:

**You can make the following changes to your script**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# There are four changes made to the script:
# 1. The addition of `tr` in order to eliminate '\r'.
# 2. Removal of '[' and ']' inside the `jq` command.
# 3. Addition of `jq --slurp` to enforce your specified JSON format. 
# 4. Addition of double-quotes around `$lel` to prevent splitting.

 
lel=$(while read cidr ; do 
       cidr=$(echo "$cidr" | tr -d '\r' );     
       jq -n --arg CIDR "$cidr" '{"source":$CIDR,"protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions": {"destinationPortRange":{"max": 65535,"min": 1},"sourcePortRange": {"min":521,
"max": 65535}  }}' 
  done < lol | jq --slurp )
echo "$lel"
```

---

##### Alternative answer

You can "repair" the file containing our list of CIDRs:

```
cp lol lol_old
cat lol_old | tr -d '\r' > lol
```

Then, you can use the earlier version of your script, albeit with the corrections explained in #2-4 comments of the script included above.

#### Explanation

The reason for the `\r` found in your output is actually found in the formatting of your particular file containing your CIDRs, which happens to follow Windows - and not Unix - line termination standard.

The `\r` symbol you see in your output is actually present in your source file as well, where it is used along with `\n` to terminate each  individual line. Both `\r` and `\n` are invisible characters.
The combination of `\r\n` is known as CRLF - carriage return + line feed - which is a remnant from the age of typewriters, yet for some reason is still used by Windows systems. On the other hand, Unix uses only LF to terminate lines, where it is represented by `\n` in its escaped form.

To confirm this peciular behavior, you can try executing the following:

```bash
head -n 1 lol | xxd -ps 
312e312e312e302f32320d0a
```

In the above output - the first line of your file converted to its hex form - ends with `0d0a`. This HEX combination represent CR+LF. On the other hand, if you execute the following directly inside of your Bash terminal:

```bash
echo "abcd"  | xxd -ps
616263640a
```

you will find that the output follows Unix standard, where the line termination uses simple `0a`, i.e. the hex representation of LF.

**Note:** This line-termination issue is incredibly common, widespread and something one always needs to be on the lookout for operating from inside Unix on files that may have been generated under Windows.

---

---

##### Info regarding `jq`

The above example (the `while read` loop) sends its output to the terminal, but you can of course use redirection if you need to store it in a file, using the standard syntax:

```bash
while read cidr; do [...] ; done < cidr.txt > outcidr.json
```

This file will contain the pretty-printed JSON output, but if you need/prefer your output to be contstrained to a single line, you can do:

```bash
cat outcidr.json | tr -d '\n' | tr -s ' '
```

More importantly, if you ever in the future end up with a single-line, complex JSON output that looks impossible to decipher, `jq` can be used to reformat and pretty-print it`:

```bash
echo '[{"source":"1.1.1.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}},{"source":"2.2.2.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}},{"source":"3.3.3.0/24","protocol":"17","isStateless":true,"udpOptions":{"destinationPortRange":{"max":55555,"min":10001},"sourcePortRange":{"min":521,"max":65535}}}]' > bad_output.json

cat bad_output.json | tr -d '\r' | jq '' 

[
  {
    "source": "1.1.1.0/24",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 55555,
        "min": 10001
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "source": "2.2.2.0/24",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 55555,
        "min": 10001
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "source": "3.3.3.0/24",
    "protocol": "17",
    "isStateless": true,
    "udpOptions": {
      "destinationPortRange": {
        "max": 55555,
        "min": 10001
      },
      "sourcePortRange": {
        "min": 521,
        "max": 65535
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```bash
# Getting first-order keys for each of the 3 objects 
 
jq '.[] | keys' bad_output.json 

[
  "isStateless",
  "protocol",
  "source",
  "udpOptions"
]
[
  "isStateless",
  "protocol",
  "source",
  "udpOptions"
]
[
  "isStateless",
  "protocol",
  "source",
  "udpOptions"
]
```

```bash
# Getting values corresponding to the selected key"  
jq '.[] | .source ' outcidr.txt 
"1.1.1.0/22"
"2.2.2.0/24"
"5.5.5.0/21"
"6.6.0.0/16"
```

Comment: Was actually typing up the update when I noticed your comment. It was impossible for me to learn of this issue , as the author of the question edited the question itself instead of posting a comment under my original answer, resulting in no notification.